# Can I install RAM that has lower frequency than what is specified in the Processor System Memory Specification?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

To be precise, I am trying to build a new computer from scratch with the following specifications:
Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 2200G
https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-3-2200g

MoBo: MSI A320M pro vd/s
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/A320M-PRO-VD-S#support-mem-13

On the processor's page, under system memory specification, they say 2993 MHz however, i believe it's a typo and it should be 2933MHz . The compatibility list on the MoBo page shows 3000MHz ram supports 2933Mhz. However, minimum 8GB DDR4 is available at 3000MHz. But I want a 4GB ram.

So, what if I install a lower frequency ram, that is 2666Mhz of ram, which is also supported by the MoBo.
Thank you, for your time to read this question. Apologies, if you find it stupid. :)

Comment: You can indeed install a 4GB 2666mhz RAM onto it but I wouldn't recommend it if you're planning to use the APU/multitasking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TL;DR Yes, you can.

What's given is:

1. A motherboard that supports DDR4 speeds up to 3200MHz.
2. A CPU that supports DDR4 speeds up to 2933MHz.
3. And you that want to install a RAM module that is 2666MHz.

Before we get the answer let's consider a few examples.

First example: We have a motherboard, that's maximum supported RAM speed is 2666MHz, and a CPU, that's maximum supported RAM speed is 2966MHz. What's gonna happen if we install a 3200MHz RAM module? The answer is motherboard will force RAM to operate at motherboard's maximum speed which is 2666MHz.

Second example: We have a motherboard that's maximum RAM speed is 3200MHz, CPU's maximum is 2400MHz. What's gonna happen if we install a ram module with crazy 3600MHz clock? The answer is motherboard will drop down RAM speed to match CPU's maximum supported clock speed which is 2400MHz. Even though you spend a couple hundreds of dollars on 3600MHz DDR4 module you will still only get 2400MHz from it, because CPU is gonna be a bottleneck for it.

And for better understanding of how all this throttling thing works, the third example: Our motherboard and CPU can work with 3200MHz memory. The first RAM module's speed is 3200, the second's is 2933, and the third one's is 2133. Whose clock speed will motherboard select? The answer is the lowest of all memory modules, which is 2133MHz. Every single module will be operating at the lowest speed of all of them. 3200, 2933 and 2133 will throttle down to 2133.

Now we can make a conclusion: Motherboard will throttle down RAM clock to the maximum CPU's supported RAM speed and/or to the lowest of all installed RAM modules.

So yes, you can install a 2666MHz module on this system. Any module that's lower than 2933MHz will be perfectly fine, even 1600MHz. But the best choice would still be 2933MHz module.

Comment: Would you know how the motherboard can detect/test the maximum operational clock speed? Does the RAM tell the motherboard its max operational clock speed or does the motherboard ramp up the access speed and test which speed it fails at and use the last stable clock speed?

Comment: Every memory module has some firmware and a controller and those modules have standardized interfaces and protocols by which they exchange information with the motherboard before being ramped up, so it's the first one, the ram module knows its capabilities (those were programmed at the factory) and the motherboards then does whatever it wants to do with that information, it wouldn't go above and beyond to check where the ram begins to crumble, that is kinda dangerous, it doesn't mean it's impossible however, if you've ever tried to overclock your memory you'd know that if you go above it fails

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Yes

Compatibility states the maximum value supported by the manufacturer, not the only / minimum value supported.